# Reponsive Grid layout

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am trying to create a responsive layout. By default, I am using Grid layout and make grid column width definition ratio (30%-70%) like this.
[image]

So that, when I resize form, the components still keep ratio is 30-70%.
But for further step, I would like wrapping it to vertical orientation when form size reach component minimum size.
Example: when I try to resize form'size to 300 device-independent unit, It should not resize components anymore, but wrapping it like this:
[image]

Would you please help me to fulfill this solution?

Comment: you can use Wrap Panel instead of grid , set orientation to Horizontal and also set minimum width for controls inside wrap panel it will automatically adjust the control inside it to next column if  required minimum space is not available.

Comment: Yes, for the second picture which I showed, I used Wrap panel, but if directly use it, I need to specified each component width also, the width is hard specified & I don't want like that, I need it still keep the ratio 3-7, just wrapping when it match the min size.

Answer (score 0):

I used a `RelativePanel` to achieve it this way. The **red colored** portion of your sample is equivalent to my `relLeftPanel` and the **blue colored** portion is my `scrollRightPanel`. I put these two inside a `RelativePanel` and used the following `VisualStateManager` to make it work accordingly.

Visual State manager code:

```
  <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup>

            <VisualState x:Name="MobileView">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0"/>
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="relLeftPanel.(RelativePanel.AlignTopWithPanel)" Value="True"/>
                    <Setter Target="relLeftPanel.(RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel)" Value="True"/>
                    <Setter Target="relLeftPanel.(RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel)" Value="True"/>

                    <Setter Target="scrollRightPanel.(RelativePanel.Below)" Value="relLeftPanel"/>
                    <Setter Target="scrollRightPanel.(RelativePanel.AlignBottomWithPanel)" Value="True"/>
                    <Setter Target="relLeftPanel.(RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel)" Value="True"/>
                    <Setter Target="relLeftPanel.(RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel)" Value="True"/>
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>

            <VisualState x:Name="TabletView">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="720"/>
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="relLeftPanel.(RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel)" Value="True"/>
                    <Setter Target="relLeftPanel.(RelativePanel.AlignTopWithPanel)" Value="True"/>
                    <Setter Target="relLeftPanel.(RelativePanel.AlignBottomWithPanel)" Value="True"/>                       

                    <Setter Target="scrollRightPanel.(RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel)" Value="True"/>
                    <Setter Target="scrollRightPanel.(RelativePanel.AlignTopWithPanel)" Value="True"/>
                    <Setter Target="scrollRightPanel.(RelativePanel.AlignBottomWithPanel)" Value="True"/>
                    <Setter Target="scrollRightPanel.(RelativePanel.RightOf)" Value="relLeftPanel"/>
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, I have find-out a solution that's embedded the WrapPanel inside a Grid (which have column definition 3-7).

```
<Grid Loaded="Grid_Loaded" SizeChanged="Grid_SizeChanged" Name="grid">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="7*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <WrapPanel Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Name="txt01" Background="Red" Text="30%" Foreground="White" TextAlignment="Center" Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Grid}}, Path=ColumnDefinitions[0].ActualWidth, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, Mode=OneWay}" MinWidth="100"/>
        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Name="txt02" Background="Blue" Grid.Column="1" Text="70%" Foreground="White" TextAlignment="Center" Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Grid}}, Path=ColumnDefinitions[1].ActualWidth, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, Mode=OneWay}" MinWidth="100"/>
    </WrapPanel>
</Grid>
```

-- One issue happened that's the Component item's width was binding to Grid's ColumnDefinition Actual Width, but the width does not updated when the Grid_Sized changed.